# Xamarin.Forms Introduction Guid

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I finished the functionalities of my app. Now when user first time login i need to make introduction guide on every page, with a short text Myabe some alert. Also on the dialog need chechbox , if he check the guide wont show again. I dont know where to start and how to organize this. Any example, practise to start. On all the dialogs will be static text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer any sample which guides you to create `Tutorial Screen`.

You can use built in `Carousel View` to have that as well.

Here I'm sharing one of that: [How to add tutorial screen in Xamarin.Forms](https://github.com/sthewissen/KickassUI.FancyTutorial)

**Edit**

To add it on every single page, you can use custom Popup, which can be created using [Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup)

Comment: This is on all page i need a something like popup with static text and checkbox on every page

Comment: Please find the Edited answer

Comment: stn like this : https://dzone.com/articles/xamarinforms-custom-popup

Comment: Yes, concept is same, but by using this plugin, it helps to reduce lot more code, and adding more customization.

Comment: how to import the popup view on every page?

Comment: I made popup:<<pages:PopupPage> </pages:PopupPage> on that page i add what i need . Now how to import in the view on other page?

Comment: Use .Navigation.PushPopupAsync(new YourPopup()); to open that popup

Comment: Yes it open and when i press close with  PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new PopupForm()); its open again

Comment: ```
public MainPage(){
 InitializeComponent();
 BindingContext = viewModel;
 PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new OdberiFirmaPopup());
}
```

Comment: On close you have to pop that page like this:   PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAllAsync();

Comment: And how to organize with checkbox. It need to show everytime if checkbox is not selected.Once when the user select the checkbox it should never show